In VSCode Remote SSH is there a way to connect as a user in the "AllowUsers" group then escalate to another user?
My server has a restricted user for connecting via ssh to limit attack surface. I connect as this user and then switch users to another. Is it possible to do this with the Remote SSH extension in VSCode? Otherwise, what is the typical workaround?
